# Add constraints to linear regression which make some of the coefficients positive

Tags: r, regression, constrained-regression

I run a linear model which is about `sales~ Investments`, denote the `Investments` as `I` and sales as `Y`. There are nine different investments in total, so `I` is `I1,I2..,I9`.

Using the following `lm` code, we can get a model.

```
mod1 <- lm(Y ~ I1 + I2 +...+I9)
summary(mod1)$coefficient
```

There are some coefficients such as `I3` and `I4` are negative, however, they should not be negative in reality. My question is how to add a constraints to limit the coefficients of `I3` and `I4` be a positive number?